# Ordering intermediate variables in Gekko

Tags: python, arraylist, ranking, gekko

I am writing a python code to solve a MINLP problem in Gekko.
I have an independent variable x and a list of intermediate variables Int=[Int_1,Int_2,...Int_n], which are functions of x.

I would like to derive a list RankedInt, which includes elements of Int in an decreasing order. I do not know how to keep the connections between x and RankedInt, i.e. when x takes different values, RankedInt will also change.

I tried using np.sort on Int, but it will only sort Int regarding the initial guess of x and will not change during the optimization process.

Thanks for any answers or discussions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sort function in Gekko. Depending on the intended use of the sorted list, you may be able to arrive at a similar result. For example, if the intent is to find the maximum or minimum value of a list of intermediate variables then the `m.max3()` function is available. As another example, if it is a [minimax problem](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/MiniMax) (minimize the maximum value) then try a reformulation of the problem such as:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x1,x2,x3,Z = m.Array(m.Var,4)
m.Minimize(Z)
m.Equation(x1+x2+x3==15)
m.Equations([Z>=x1,Z>=x2,Z>=x3])
m.solve()
print('x1: ',x1.value[0])
print('x2: ',x2.value[0])
print('x3: ',x3.value[0])
print('Z:  ',Z.value[0])
```

These are just two examples. There are also resources on [schedule optimization](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ScheduleOptimization) if it is related to that area.